# Haproxy load balancing for download host

Tags: haproxy

I'm rather new to load balancing concepts and wanted to use Haproxy to load balance between my web servers for a downloads site. I'm a bit confused as to how it works.

The goal is to setup HAProxy to forward requests to different servers as to expand my total download capacity. For example I have 5x 1Gbit/s servers. If one is running HAProxy and 4 are running my web servers, would the total download speed for the cluster be 4Gbit/s or would it be limited to 1Gbit/s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the situation you describe, you'd still be limited to 1gbps, but it would be spread over your 4 other servers.

It might be possible to get more out of it, but we'd need more details about those 5 connections and the underlying infrastructure.

Comment: As of now, nothing is setup. I have 5 dedicated servers each with their own public IP address. I'm not set on HaProxy specifically, it was just easy to deploy and I'm not yet set on Layer 4 or 7 proxying. Could there be a better solution then haproxy? Something like a "forwarder" which would route DNS to each IP or something. My newbieness shows.

Comment: If you're not set on Layer7, then LVS configured in Direct Server Return mode would give you what you want. In that mode, inbound connections get load-balanced but the "backend" servers send their replies directly to the client, giving you their combined bandwidth.

Comment: Nice! http://blog.haproxy.com/2011/07/29/layer-4-load-balancing-direct-server-return-mode/ I'd vote up but need the rep to do so!

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I was talking about. Happy load-balancing!